# Can I access the particle system through Python to build custom simulations?

Tags: python, particles

I would like to build my own custom simulation in python, using blender's particle system as a base.

---

What I need:

- Load all particles of current frame (I'd at least need locations and, ideally, velocities)
- Work some coding magic specific to my simulation
- save output as new frame

I heard that, perhaps, this might be possible by accessing and modifying the particle cache. But any pointer to how something like this could be done would be helpful. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

I managed to get it to work by modifying this script phonybone posted to Blender Artists:
[Point Cache Doctor Script (BA)](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?318831-Point-Cache-Doctor-script)

For the most part I just took that script and ran with it although I did some minor changes to get some extra functionality. - My PyFu isn't strong so it might be that I made it worse in style that way but it worked for me. Here is my version (the portion that does the importing/exporting - Most of it is completely unchanged)

---

```
import os
import struct
from os import path
from math import *
import random

def pack_string(v, size):
    return struct.pack('%ds' % size, v.encode(encoding='UTF-8'))


def unpack_string(b, size):
    return struct.unpack('%ds' % size, b)[0].decode(encoding='UTF-8')


def pack_uint(v):
    return struct.pack('I', v)


def unpack_uint(b):
    return struct.unpack('I', b)[0]


def pack_float(v):
    return struct.pack('f', v)


def unpack_float(b):
    return struct.unpack('f', b)[0]


def pack_vector(v):
    return struct.pack('fff', v[0], v[1], v[2])


def unpack_vector(b):
    return struct.unpack('fff', b)


def pack_quaternion(v):
    return struct.pack('ffff', v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3])


def unpack_quaternion(b):
    return struct.unpack('ffff', b)


def pack_color(v):
    return struct.pack('ffff', v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3])


def unpack_color(b):
    return struct.unpack('ffff', b)


class ParticleTimes:
    __slots__=('birthtime', 'lifetime', 'dietime')

    def __init__(self, birthtime, lifetime, dietime):
        self.birthtime=birthtime
        self.lifetime=lifetime
        self.dietime=dietime


def pack_particle_times(v):
    return struct.pack('fff', v.birthtime, v.lifetime, v.dietime)


def unpack_particle_times(b):
    birthtime, lifetime, dietime=struct.unpack('fff', b)
    return ParticleTimes(birthtime, lifetime, dietime)


class BoidData:
    __slots__=('health', 'acceleration', 'state_id', 'mode')

    def __init__(self, health, acceleration, state_id, mode):
        self.health=health
        self.acceleration=acceleration
        self.state_id=state_id
        self.mode=mode


def pack_boid(v):
    return struct.pack('ffffhh', v.health, v.acceleration[0], v.acceleration[1], v.acceleration[2], v.state_id, v.mode)


def unpack_boid(b):
    health, acc0, acc1, acc2, state_id, mode=struct.unpack('ffffhh', b)
    return BoidData(health, (acc0, acc1, acc2), state_id, mode)


_flag_map={
    0x00010000: 'compress',
    0x00020000: 'extra_data',
}


class TypeDesc:
    """Data type descriptor"""

    def __init__(self, index, name, size, pack, unpack):
        self.index=index
        self.name=name
        self.size=size
        self.pack=pack
        self.unpack=unpack

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __repr__(self):
        return "TypeDesc(name=%r, size=%d)" % (self.name, self.size)


_data_types_softbody=(
    TypeDesc(1, 'LOCATION', 12, pack_vector, unpack_vector),
    TypeDesc(2, 'VELOCITY', 12, pack_vector, unpack_vector),
)

_data_types_particles=(
    TypeDesc(0, 'INDEX', 4, pack_uint, unpack_uint),
    TypeDesc(1, 'LOCATION', 12, pack_vector, unpack_vector),
    TypeDesc(2, 'VELOCITY', 12, pack_vector, unpack_vector),
    TypeDesc(3, 'ROTATION', 16, pack_quaternion, unpack_quaternion),
    TypeDesc(4, 'AVELOCITY', 12, pack_vector, unpack_vector),
    TypeDesc(5, 'SIZE', 4, pack_float, unpack_float),
    TypeDesc(6, 'TIMES', 12, pack_particle_times, unpack_particle_times),
    TypeDesc(7, 'BOIDS', 20, pack_boid, unpack_boid),
)

_data_types_cloth=(
    TypeDesc(1, 'LOCATION', 12, pack_vector, unpack_vector),
    TypeDesc(2, 'VELOCITY', 12, pack_vector, unpack_vector),
    TypeDesc(4, 'XCONST', 12, pack_vector, unpack_vector),
)

_data_types_smoke=(
    TypeDesc(1, 'SMOKE_LOW', 12, pack_vector, unpack_vector),
    TypeDesc(2, 'SMOKE_HIGH', 12, pack_vector, unpack_vector),
)

_data_types_dynamicpaint=(
    TypeDesc(3, 'DYNAMICPAINT', 16, pack_color, unpack_color),
)

_data_types_rigidbody=(
    TypeDesc(1, 'LOCATION', 12, pack_vector, unpack_vector),
    TypeDesc(3, 'ROTATION', 16, pack_quaternion, unpack_quaternion),
)

_type_map={
    0: ('SOFTBODY', _data_types_softbody),
    1: ('PARTICLES', _data_types_particles),
    2: ('CLOTH', _data_types_cloth),
    3: ('SMOKE_DOMAIN', _data_types_smoke),
    4: ('SMOKE_HIGHRES', _data_types_smoke),
    5: ('DYNAMICPAINT', _data_types_dynamicpaint),
    6: ('RIGIDBODY', _data_types_rigidbody),
}


def cache_file_list(directory, index=0):
    """Cache frame files in a directory, sorted by frame
    """

    return sorted(cache_files(directory, index), key=lambda item: item[0])


def cache_files(directory, index=0):
    """Cache frame files in a directory
    """

    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        try:
            base, ext=path.splitext(filename)
            parts=base.split('_')
            if len(parts) in (2, 3):
                cframe=int(parts[1])
                cindex=int(parts[2]) if len(parts) >= 3 else 0
                if cindex == index:
                    yield cframe, filename
        except:
            pass


class CacheFrame():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.totpoint = 0
        self.data_types = tuple()
        self.data = tuple()

    def get_data_type(self, name):
        for dt in self.data_types:
            if dt.name == name:
                return dt
        return None

    def get_data(self, name):
        for dt, data in zip(self.data_types, self.data):
            if dt.name == name:
                return data
        return None

    def set_data(self, name, values):
        self.data = tuple(data if dt.name != name else values for dt, data in zip(self.data_types, self.data))

    def read(self, directory, read_data):
        cachetype = ""
        data_types = {}

        f = open(path.join(directory, self.filename), "rb")
        try:
            cachetype, data_types = self.read_header(f)

            if read_data:
                self.read_points(f)
            else:
                self.data = None

        finally:
            f.close()

        return cachetype, data_types

    def read_header(self, f):
        bphysics = unpack_string(f.read(8), 8)
        if bphysics != 'BPHYSICS':
            raise Exception("Not a valid BPHYSICS cache file")

        typeflag = unpack_uint(f.read(4))

        cachetype, data_types = _type_map[typeflag & 0x0000FFFF]
        self.cachetype = cachetype

        for bits, flag in _flag_map.items():
            setattr(self, flag, bool(typeflag & bits))

        self.totpoint = unpack_uint(f.read(4))

        data_types_flag = unpack_uint(f.read(4))
        # frame has filtered data types list in case not all data types are stored
        self.data_types = tuple(filter(lambda dt: ((1<<dt.index) & data_types_flag) != 0, data_types))

        return cachetype, data_types

    def read_points(self, f):
        data = tuple([None] * self.totpoint for dt in self.data_types)

        if self.compress:
            raise Exception("Compressed caches are not supported yet, sorry ...")
            return data

        def interleaved():
            for k in range(self.totpoint):
                yield k, tuple(dt.unpack(f.read(dt.size)) if dt else None for dt in self.data_types)

        for k, data_point in interleaved():
            for data_list, value in zip(data, data_point):
                data_list[k] = value

        self.data = data

    def write(self, directory):
        f = open(path.join(directory, self.filename), "wb")
        try:
            self.write_header(f)
            self.write_points(f)

        finally:
            f.close()

    def write_header(self, f):
        f.write(pack_string('BPHYSICS', 8))

        typeflag = 0
        for index, (name, _) in _type_map.items():
            if name == self.cachetype:
                typeflag = typeflag | index
                break

        for bits, flag in _flag_map.items():
            if getattr(self, flag):
                typeflag = typeflag | bits

        f.write(pack_uint(typeflag))

        f.write(pack_uint(self.totpoint))

        data_types_flag = 0
        for dt in self.data_types:
            data_types_flag = data_types_flag | (1<<dt.index)
        f.write(pack_uint(data_types_flag))

    def write_points(self, f):
        if self.compress:
            raise Exception("Compressed caches are not supported yet, sorry ...")
            return data

        for k in range(self.totpoint):
            for data, dt in zip(self.data, self.data_types):
                f.write(dt.pack(data[k]))

class PointCache():
    def __init__(self, directory, index=0):
        self.files = cache_file_list(directory, index)
        if not self.files:
            raise Exception("No point cache files for index %d in directory %s" % (index, directory))

        self.start_frame, self.info_filename = self.files[0]
        self.end_frame, self.last_filename = self.files[-1]

        info_frame = CacheFrame(self.info_filename)
        cachetype, data_types = info_frame.read(directory, read_data=False)

        self.cachetype = cachetype
        self.data_types = data_types

        for flag in _flag_map.values():
            setattr(self, flag, getattr(info_frame, flag))
        self.totpoint = info_frame.totpoint

    def get_data_type(self, name):
        for dt in self.data_types:
            if dt.name == name:
                return dt
        return None
```

---

I hope I made no mistake in the indentation there.
Most of it is just utility functions.
In usage, you'll first load the cache you have thus far:

```
cache = PointCache(my_directory,my_cache_index)
```

Then you can load frames from the cache. For instance, if you want to get the very last frame in the cache (I believe that was one of my changes), you can go:

```
frame=CacheFrame(cache.last_filename) # at this point only parts are loaded
frame.read(my_directory,True) #now everything actually is in place
```

And now you can access all the data you might want. - phonybone used this in the Tube project for cloth simulation. My usage is for particle simulation. Both works just fine. For instance, if you want the location of all your particles, you can go:

```
locdata=frame.get_data('LOCATION') # [(x1,y1,z1),(x2,y2,z2),...]
```

You can modify it somehow and then save it again with

```
frame.set_data('LOCATION',new_locdata) #at this point it's only in python
frame.write(my_directory) # this updates the cache
```

Make sure you spell the data strings right (I had a minor crisis because I accidentally added an extra `I` in `'VELOCITIY'` - in the current implementation this just fails silently rather than leading to an error. Maybe that should be changed.) and you can do completely arbitrary changes to your cache.
Furthermore, for this to show up in Blender, you gotta set the storage location to "External". - I recommend keeping a backup around. - And in fact, the original version of this script had an utility function to do just that. I only copied over what's strictly necessary to read and write your caches though.

Happy Blending!

P.S. I made this a Community Wiki in case somebody has some clever/useful revisions for the above python script.